# Convert date time to NSDate from NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, xcode4.5, nstimezone

Time zone always made trouble for me. This time I have to convert date-time , that I have in NSSTring to NSDate.

I am doing something like this.

```
NSString *myStringDate=@"14-11-2012 4:09:00 PM +0500"

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a Z"];

NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:myStringDate];
NSLog(@"%@",aDate);
```

but I am having the output like this

`14-11-2012 11:09:00 +0000`

Also, no AM/PM is setting :-(

What I want is `14-11-2012 4:09:00 PM +0500` i.e same Date-Time that I have in string.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: also, see: WWDC 2011 Session Videos, "Session 117 - Performing Calendar Calculations"

Answer (score 1):

the output of your converting  is giving the GMT time

```
NSString *myStringDate=@"14-11-2012 4:09:00 PM +0500"

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a Z"];

NSDate *aDate = [formatter dateFromString:myStringDate];



 NSDateFormatter* df_utc = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
 [df_utc setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"];

 NSDateFormatter* df_local = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
 [df_local setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"]];
 [df_local setDateFormat:@"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz"];

 NSString* ts_utc_string = [df_utc stringFromDate:aDate];
 NSString* ts_local_string = [df_local stringFromDate:aDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Is the Change need to be taken.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:ss a "];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The conversion looks correct, but the default output is in UTC time (`+0000`) and with a 24h clock which is why you don't get the AM/PM distinction (“01:00 PM” would be 13:00). You also need to format the *output* if you want a specific representation (`[formatter stringFromDate:aDate]`)…

For the UTC issue you need to select the time zone of your choice, by giving that choice in place of `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]`. Try `[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]` for starters.